# When is $[0,1]^K$ submetrizable or even metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $K$ is a compact space. Then could the function space $I^K$ be submetrizable, even metrizable? In other words, in general, if $I^A$ can be submetrizable (metrizable) for some space $A$, what's condition that $A$ should satisfying?

Comment: What topology do you have on $I^A$? If $A$ is uncountable, the product topology is not metrizable.

Comment: Really, I want to know the results on the topology of uniform convergence, the topology of pointwise convergence and the compact-open topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is compact, $I^A$ is metrizable with the metric being the uniform norm.  That is, $d(f,g):=\sup_{a\in A} d(f(a),g(a))$.

Comment: Do you mean that if $A$ only needs to be compact then $I^A$ has this metric $d$?

Comment: @John Correct.  In general, $X^Y$ is metrizable if $Y$ is compact and $X$ is a metric space.  [Hatcher's Appendix](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf) has a proof of this (Proposition A.13).

Comment: It's nice! Do you know other conditions on $A$ such that will make the space $I^A$ metrizable? For example $A$ is countable and so on.

Comment: $A$ sigma-compact and locally compact Hausdorff will also guarantee that all functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the compact-open topology will be metrizable, and this is necessary as well, for functions with codomain the reals.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, could you give me a proof for it?